# How to start controller in OpenDaylight Helium (Karaf based)?

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf, openflow, opendaylight, sdn

I've downloaded the software and have run ./bin/karaf
what is the further procedure?
How to start controller? I want to use REST APIs to add flow entries.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link:
https://www.opendaylight.org/sites/opendaylight/files/bk-install-guide-20141002.pdf

1. install the necessary features
2. open the dlux web page using (odl ip address:8181/dlux/ndex.html)
   there you can find the services which you want.

Comment: The link sends 403 forbidden.